# What should I learn to become a web design expert? I am from engineering background

Tags: website-design, resource-recommendations

I'm a computer science graduate having a passion for web design. Almost two years ago, I started learning web design. I designed few websites as well. Every day I try to improve my designing skills a lot.

I just want to become a **highly skilled, professional** web designer!

I'm good at programming and I can design good aesthetic websites as well. As I told you I've been pursuing webdesign for the past 2 years (through online blogs & e-books). I have a good knowledge in layout design, color schemes, grid systems, and obviously, coding.

One thing which makes me feel weak is that I'm not a graduate from an arts or design school.

Can I become a skilled designer who is able to design as designers with an arts background do?

Can you suggest me something which takes me from a newbie to the advanced level?

I'm not a newbie in designing! I know the basic things and I'm also working as a junior designer. I just want to learn more and more to become an expert web designer.

I hope you can give me proper guidance & suggestions..

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should read the excellent answers in the link above your question because it answers a lot of your questions.  Regardless of the application/medium a majority of the same rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an arts or design degree to be a good designer. It helps, sure, but it isn't necessary. The most important thing you need instead of a degree is *experience*. That is exactly the thing that takes you to the next level: work experience.

I'd advise you to keep on doing web design work, read about it both offline and on. There's gazilliions of blogs about web design, but I'd start with [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) and [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/) and work your way from there.

Other good resources are tutorials, video courses, and blogs about web design.

Comment: the first para in your answer makes me feel confident!
i'm reading bunch of blogs (including one you mentioned) and i practise too. Is there anything which is taught in design schools, which makes them special from others like me?

Comment: I have no clue--I never attended any :)

Comment: could you upvote my question atleast? it helps me! :)

Comment: @bharat art school will cover a lot of design fundamentals and fine art skills. On your own, you may want to delve into art and design history books. Read up on typography. Practice drawing, painting, etc.